# edit web.config to pass parameters

Tags: iis, parameters, web-config, isapi

Using Delphi, I have created a ISAPI .dll file  called myISAPI.dll
It is in a virtual folder on IIS called myISAPI, the default document of the folder is myISAPI.dll

Thus, I can call my dll by addressing http://webserver/myISAPI/

If I want to actually use the .dll, I have to address this way: http://webserver/myISAPI/myISAPI.dll?parameters

If I try http://webserver/myISAPI/parameters I get "Not Found" obviously.

How can I edit the web.config to prepend "myISAPI.dll?"  or is there another way of catching the parameters?  I have tried redirects with no success

**** EDIT ****
While this is similar to the question indicated, I had problems that others may face.  I had not tried URL_REWRITE because it was not present in my IIS manager.  I had installed it, at least when I tried to install it said "already installed"
I solved it by editing

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\MajorVersion (set to 9)
Uninstalled URL_REWRITE  (reboot)
Uninstalled Web Platform Installer  (reboot)
Install Web Platform Installer  (reboot)
Install URL_REWRITE  (reboot)  {It would NOT install from WPI, I had to download and install separately}
```

The regex I am using is  ^([^/]+)/?$

One and a half hours in, can finally start work.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: You should remove delphi tag because this is not a Delphi problem at all.

Comment: @Peter  - It might work, after I mangle HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\MajorVersion and then Manually install url_rewrite  and then reboot my PC 3 times.  If this works - you get the points

Comment: @ Francois, I added Delphi, because someone ALLWAYS comments "what are you using?"  I will, just because it is you, remove the tag.